# Using a list / dataframe / vector to assign labels to column names of a dataframe with Hmisc

Tags: r, label, hmisc

I would like to use the column `Variables` of a dataframe:

```
  Variables Varcode  Country Ccode  2000  2001 
1 Power     P        France  FR     1213  1234
2 Happiness H        France  FR     1872  2345
3 Power     P        UK      UK     1726  6433
4 Happiness H        UK      UK     2234  9082
```

to assign labels to the column names (from variable P onwards) of another (reshaped) dataframe:

```
  Year      Country Ccode P(label=Power) H(label=Happiness)
1 2000      France  FR    1213           1872  
2 2001      France  FR    1234           2345
3 2000      UK      UK    1726           2234
4 2001      UK      UK    6433           9082
```

I had the following in mind:

Before reshaping

```
library(Hmisc)
LabelList <- as.data.frame(df1$Varcode)
LabelList <- as.character(LabelList) #(EDIT)
```

Reshaping

```
df2 %>% 
  select(-Variables) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`2000`:`2001`) %>% 
  unite(Country_Ccode, Country, Ccode, sep = "_") %>% 
  spread(Varcode, val) %>% 
  separate(Country_Ccode, c("Country", "Ccode"), sep = "_")
```

After reshaping (EDIT:the label function only allows a vector of 1)

```
for(i in LabelList){
label(df2[,i]) <- LabelList[i]
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(List, i) : undefined columns selected
Error : Unsupported index type: factor
```

After as.character(LabelList) the error becomes:

```
Error : Column `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, .., )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: one of your variables is a factor when the function is expecting a string (most likely). do an `str(yourDF)` and figure out which column is a factor and change it to a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. So, I will show stepwise what I have tried.

#### 1. Reshaping without `label<-()`

In a first attempt, I resorted to `data.table` which I am more acquainted.

```
library(data.table)   # for melt() and dcast()
library(magrittr)     # for piping %>%
df1 %>% 
  setDT() %>%
  melt(measure.vars = patterns("^20"), variable.name = "Year") %>% 
  dcast(... ~ Varcode + Variables)
```

> ```
>    Country Ccode Year H_Happiness P_Power
> 1:  France    FR 2000        1872    1213
> 2:  France    FR 2001        2345    1234
> 3:      UK    UK 2000        2234    1726
> 4:      UK    UK 2001        9082    6433
> ```

Now, the column headers of the value vars contain `Varcode` and `Variables`. I have tried this because I was unsure what the OP is aiming to achieve with using `Hmisc::label()`.

#### 2. Reshaping with `label<-()`

```
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  setDT() %>%
  melt(measure.vars = patterns("^20"), variable.name = "Year") %>% 
  dcast(Year + Country + Ccode ~ Varcode)
```

> ```
>    Year Country Ccode    H    P
> 1: 2000  France    FR 1872 1213
> 2: 2000      UK    UK 2234 1726
> 3: 2001  France    FR 2345 1234
> 4: 2001      UK    UK 9082 6433
> ```

Now, we have to add lables to columns `H` and `P`.

```
# create list of labels
Lbl <- df1[, .(Variables, Varcode)] %>% unique()
Lbl
```

> ```
>    Variables Varcode
> 1:     Power       P
> 2: Happiness       H
> ```

```
# set labels
for (i in seq_len(nrow(Lbl))) {
  Hmisc::label(df2[[Lbl$Varcode[i]]]) <- Lbl$Variables[i]
}
str(df2)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    4 obs. of  5 variables:
>  $ Year   : Factor w/ 2 levels "2000","2001": 1 1 2 2
>  $ Country: chr  "France" "UK" "France" "UK"
>  $ Ccode  : chr  "FR" "UK" "FR" "UK"
>  $ H      : 'labelled' int  1872 2234 2345 9082
>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Happiness"
>  $ P      : 'labelled' int  1213 1726 1234 6433
>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Power"
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
>  - attr(*, "sorted")= chr  "Year" "Country" "Ccode"
> ```

Now, both columns `H` and `P` have been labeled accordingly.

#### 3. Completing OP's approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% 
  select(-Variables) %>% 
  gather(Year, val,`2000`:`2001`) %>% 
  spread(Varcode, val)
df2
```

> ```
>   Country Ccode Year    H    P
> 1  France    FR 2000 1872 1213
> 2  France    FR 2001 2345 1234
> 3      UK    UK 2000 2234 1726
> 4      UK    UK 2001 9082 6433
> ```

Note that the calls to `unite()` and `separate()` have been skipped as they are not needed to reproduce the expected result.

```
Lbl <- df1 %>% 
  distinct(Varcode, Variables)
for (i in seq_len(nrow(Lbl))) {
  Hmisc::label(df2[[Lbl$Varcode[i]]]) <- Lbl$Variables[i]
}
str(df2)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  5 variables:
>  $ Country: chr  "France" "France" "UK" "UK"
>  $ Ccode  : chr  "FR" "FR" "UK" "UK"
>  $ Year   : chr  "2000" "2001" "2000" "2001"
>  $ H      : 'labelled' int  1872 2345 2234 9082
>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Happiness"
>  $ P      : 'labelled' int  1213 1234 1726 6433
>   ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Power"
> ```

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.table::fread(
"i  Variables Varcode  Country Ccode  2000  2001 
1 Power     P        France  FR     1213  1234
2 Happiness H        France  FR     1872  2345
3 Power     P        UK      UK     1726  6433
4 Happiness H        UK      UK     2234  9082
", drop = 1L, data.table = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for making my week on Monday morning. That went in one go.. Thank you so much for your effort!